# How do I load a UTF16-encoded text file in Julia?

Tags: unicode, encoding, julia

I have a text file I am (pretty sure) is encoded in UTF16, but I don't know how to load it in Julia. Do I have to load it as bytes and then convert with `UTF16String`?

Comment: Just curious, from the bash prompt, what does `file your_text_file` or `file -i your_text_file` say?

Comment: "Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode English text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to read it as bytes and then convert:

```
s = open(filename, "r") do f
    utf16(readbytes(f))
end
```

Note that `utf16` also checks for a byte-order-mark (BOM), so it will deal with endianness issues and won't include the BOM in the resulting `s`.

If you really want to avoid making a copy of the data, and you know it is native-endian, this is possible too, but you have to explicitly write a NUL terminator (since Julia UTF-16 string data internally has a NUL codepoint at the end for passing to C routines that expect NUL-terminated data):

```
s = open(filename, "r") do f
    b = readbytes(f)
    resize!(b, length(b)+2)
    b[end] = b[end-1] = 0
    UTF16String(reinterpret(UInt16, b))
end
```

However, typical UTF-16 text files will start with a BOM, and in this case the string `s` will include the BOM as its first character, which may not be what you want.